# How do you give a CircleAvatar multiple border colors in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to give a circle avatar multiple border colors in Flutter.

Bonus if you could set the % you want each color to fill.

Here is an image of what I mean, but note it wasn't that easy to do in Figma, hence the blurring of the colors. Color blending actually would not be the preferred behavior.

[image]

Comment: Just take a look here,you might get some clue . And what i think that if we increase the number of color here than we can get the required output . Do let me know if it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351136/how-can-i-color-half-of-my-circleavatar-with-one-color-and-aother-half-with-ano

Comment: Thanks. Looks very promising. Will update.

Answer (score 2):

This is what came to my mind. You can change the color list to match the Figma gradient.

[image]

```
Container(
     height: 80,
     width: 80,
     decoration: const BoxDecoration(
           gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                Colors.green,
                Colors.yellow,
                Colors.red,
                Colors.purple
           ]),
      shape: BoxShape.circle),
      child: Padding(
            //this padding will be you border size
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: const CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        foregroundImage: NetworkImage("https://i.ibb.co/rkG8cCs/112921315-gettyimages-876284806.jpg"),
                   ),
            ),
      ),
),
```

Comment: Great it worked for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution,

```
Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                                        begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                        colors: [
                                          Color(0XFF8134AF),
                                          Color(0XFFDD2A7B),
                                          Color(0XFFFEDA77),
                                          Color(0XFFF58529),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle
                                  ),
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle
                                    ),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                      child: CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 25,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(reels[i].image)
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions didn't quite do what I originally wanted, but thanks anyway!

Here is the code I have eventually ended up using. Does exactly what I want. Hope it is useful.

```
    import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: MulticolorBorderPainter(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue]),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 60,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MulticolorBorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Color> colors;

  MulticolorBorderPainter({required this.colors});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double radius = size.width / 2;
    double segmentAngle = 2 * pi / colors.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      final Paint paint = Paint()
        ..color = colors[i]
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = 4.0;  // Adjust for border thickness

      final startAngle = i * segmentAngle;
      final sweepAngle = segmentAngle;

      canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(radius, radius), radius: radius), startAngle, sweepAngle, false, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```